# How to use vert.x config read json files?

Tags: java, vert.x

I want to use vert.x config modules to read json files.

Because do not like using

```
-conf src/main/conf/my-application-conf.json
```

Sometimes we don't use complex operation commands when we need change a configuration.

I found a way to get this, please see [github](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/blob/master/core-examples/src/main/java/io/vertx/example/core/jsonstreaming/JsonStreamingExample.java)

Do you have more ways? Can we use vert.x config modules?

Except json, some type files need to write in conf. Such as yaml.

Please tell me how to use vert.x config modules to get that infomation and how to use as a jsonObject.

Thanks!

Comment: i'd like to help but i don't completely understand. you're not bootstrapping with the `-conf` flag, so that means you're not reading your config via `AbstractVerticle.config()`. are you asking how else to reference a locally stored config file? (if so, the sample code you referenced seems to do a good job of demonstrating that and doesn't require the `Vert.x Config` module). are you asking how to reference remote configs? what do you mean about writing YAML files?

Comment: Thinks ! `-conf` please see **External configuration - Let’s run on another port** of  [Vert.x Application Configuration](https://vertx.io/blog/vert-x-application-configuration/) .Now ,i want to study how to get this port in my code by vert.x Config modules when do not use `-conf` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i understand correctly, it looks like you're looking for an alternative approach to accessing config files by means other than specifying the `-conf` program argument and subsequently accessing via `AbstractVerticle.config()`.

the example you linked to seemed like a good idiomatic approach - is there something about it that doesn't suit your needs?

another way of doing this, assuming your configs are packaged in your application's jar, is to leverage the `ClassLoader` to return a stream to those resources, like so:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/my-application-conf.json")
```

while this relies on core Java APIs without requiring extra modules like Vert.x Config, it would introduce a bit of synchronous/blocking code into your codebase.

Comment: Thanks！It is help me!